# why is RoutingModule not working in my angular app?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-routing

edit : please note that everything was working fine before trying to split my app module into feature modules for lazy loading

so I'm Trying to split my app module into other feature modules so that I can use lazy loading in my angular app,

but I'm having an error

> "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink'
>   since it isn't a known property of 'h4'. ("class="col-3">
>               ]routerLink="/profile/{{castra.id}}/public">
>                 {{castra.name}}
>                "): ng:///CastraModule/CastrasComponent.html@18:85
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
>       at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
>   (compiler.js:14687)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
>   (compiler.js:22687)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
>   (compiler.js:22674)
>       at compiler.js:22617
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   (compiler.js:22617)
>       at compiler.js:22527
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.js:22526)"

this is my feature Module

```
(Imports)

@NgModule({
declarations: [
CastrasComponent,
ProfileComponent,
PublicComponent,
MenuComponent,
ReservationComponent
],
imports: [
CommonModule,
TestRoutingModule
]
})
export class CastraModule { }
```

my TestRoutingModule

```
(Imports)
const testRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'test', component: TestComponent},
{
path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent,
children: [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/profile/:id/public', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'public', component: PublicComponent},
  {path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent},
  {path: 'reservation', component: ReservationComponent},
  ]
 }
]

@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forChild(TestRoutes)
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TestRoutingModule { }
```

and the Test Module is imported in the App module so what is the problem?

Comment: `before trying to split my app module into feature modules for lazy loading` Please elaborate what exactly you're doing?

Comment: i am splitting my app module into feature modules to boost performance

Comment: Then you have to make sure that those modules import RouterModule or any other module that exports RouterModule

Comment: yes I imported routerModule in all modules and it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need? wrap it inside **`<a> and  </a>`**

```
<h4><a routerLink="menu">Part1</a></h4>
```

**EDIT**

You need to add the RouterModule to **`imports: []`** of every module where you use router directives like RouterOutlet or routerLink.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `RouterModule.forRoot(TestRoutes)` instead of `RouterModule.forChild(TestRoutes)` it works in my router files